# Are light peer review requests allowed here?

Tags: discussion

I ask this because I frequently find myself flat out of luck googling for an elegant solution and end up rolling my own extensions to accomplish whatever tasks that Magento can't accommodate out of the box.

It's very possible that some of the things I make aren't considered "best practice" and better solutions do exist somewhere out there.  The reviews that I'm speaking of wouldn't necessarily be code reviews, but rather concept reviews.  I think that such topics would be general enough to benefit a lot of folks that encounter the same problems.

As a concrete example:

> Target Version:
>
> > Magento 1.7.02 Community Edition
>
> Problem Synopsis:
>
> > Adding a block class that doesn't descend from Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links_Block to a Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links block may result in non-compliant HTML generation unless the block class wraps its own output in <li> tags.
>
> Additional Info:
>
> > I encountered this yesterday when adding a search bar in a link list.
>
> Proposed Solution
>
> > I resolved this by providing my own MyCompany_Page_Block_Template_Links template in the theme that I am building that handles the case of block classes that are not of type Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links_Block.
>
> Related Code
>
> > < code here >
>
> **Question**
>
> > **Is there a better way to accomplish this?**

Determining whether a question is "recommend opinion based X" versus "recommend industry accepted best practice" should be quite distinct in these cases.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I depends on how you ask the questions.
if your question starts with "what's the best way to..." then it might be opinion based since in a lot of cases there is no best way or there are multiple ways that are equally valid to do a thing.
If your question looks like "I have to do.... I tried it to do like this....it seams to work, but it doesn't look clean to me. Are there alternatives?" it may be a valid question.
SE encourages you to post what you tried so far so other people can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you just search for feedback, the [magento reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/magento) is always a good place.